# Can/Should I make an automatic installation of new python libraries after a git pull?

Tags: python, git, github, automation

Imagine the following situation:

1. I'm working on a python project, and I install the library `antigravity` with pip.
2. I add the function `fly()` which uses the library, and I commit and push the changes.
3. Some time after, my partner(s) run `git pull`.

How do they know that they should install the new library? By failing to run the program? Because I told them so? **Should the library install automatically?** **Is there any easy way of doing that?**

For context, in case it's relevant, I'm using python 3 and the project is stored at github. Thanks.

Comment: This is what requirements files are for. Most workflows that reuse/automate Git usage will also automate package management , driven by a `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: This question was already asked and answered in 2011 [on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120902/how-do-i-automatically-install-missing-python-modules). See also [this link](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/managing-dependencies/)

Comment: In C#, the Nuget package manager handles this; dependencies on third-party libraries are listed in a separate file (or the project file) and downloaded automatically if they don't exist on the machine. Is there something similar for python?

Comment: @mmathis: see my comment above.

Comment: @DocBrown, your second link did it for me; if you want, answer the question and I'll accept it.

Comment: @GuillermoMosse: thanks, but I don't write answers for things where I can only contribute a link (and the community here is strictly against link-only answers as well). I think, however, you should have invested a little bit more search effort into your question before asking, it took me less than a minute to find those links on Google. Try keywords "python automatic dependency" by yourself, you will find plenty of more links.